# Iterate a list for first half no of items

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, list, razor

I am trying to iterate a list for only first half of the items, and then again i want to iterate a list for only the remaining other half of the list. Any Ideas ?

```
@foreach (var category in Model.Categories.OrderBy(i => i.CategoryName))
{
  <li>
    <div id="category_@(category.SKU)" 
         class="itemBlock" 
         onclick="toggle('@(category.SKU)')">
  </li>
}
```

Comment: `.Skip(Model.Categories.Length / 2)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like:

```
var categories = Model.Categories.OrderBy(i => i.CategoryName).ToList();
int noOfCategories = categories.Count();
int half = noOfCategories/2;

for (int x = 0; x < half; x++)
{
    var category = categories[x];
    //your logic here
}
for (int x = half; x < noOfCategories; x++)
{
    var category = categories[x];
    //your logic here
}
```

Should do the trick, can't guarantee that the syntax is 100%, but that should give you all you need to do it!

Answer (score 2):

Just use a [for loop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx).

```
for(int i=0; i < Model.Categories.OrderBy(i => i.CategoryName).Count/2; i++)
{
    // do stuff
}

for(int i=Model.Categories.OrderBy(i => i.CategoryName).Count/2; i < Model.Categories.OrderBy(i => i.CategoryName).Count; i++)
{
    // do different stuff
}
```

Comment: No point ordering in the first bit of the `for` as you're just counting the result.

Comment: You're doing the sort twice there, which isn't very efficient. Sort once into a variable and use that to cut down on processing. Especially if the list has a lot of items in it.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett cut and paste got me again. :P

Answer (score 1):

I really recommend pushing that logic into your model then just get the data already formatted for the view:

```
[Serializable]
public class YourModel
{
    private int _mid
    {
        get { Categories.Count / 2; }
    }
    private int _top
    {
        get { Categories.Count - _mid; }
    }
    public List<Category> CategoriesLowerHalf
    {
        get { Categories.OrderBy(i => i.CategoryName).Take(_mid); }
    }
    public List<Category> CategoriesUpperHalf
    {
        get { Categories.OrderBy(i => i.CategoryName).GetRange(_mid, _top); }
    }
    // rest of your model
}
```

Then in your view:

```
@foreach (var category in Model.CategoriesLowerHalf)
{
   <li>
      <div id="category_@(category.SKU)" class="itemBlock" onclick="toggle('@(category.SKU)')">category.Name</div>
   </li>
 }

@foreach (var category in Model.CategoriesUpperHalf)
{
   <li>
      <div id="category_@(category.SKU)" class="itemBlock" onclick="toggle('@(category.SKU)')">category.Name</div>
   </li>
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can split the list into 2 arrays and then run a loop on each of them as desired.

Comment: Why split? Extra processing with no added value to the problem solution.

Answer (score 0):

> the following code has worked on my app.

```
                      @{
                            int a = 0;
                            int b = 0;
                        }

                   <li>
                        @foreach (var item in Model.NameHere)
                        {
                           //write code here
                            a++;
                            if (a == Model.Offices.Count() / 2)
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        @foreach (var item in Model.NameHere)
                        {

                            if (b >= Model.Offices.Count() / 2)
                            {
                                //write code here
                            }
                            b++;
                        }
                    </li>
```